# Angular - find out scopes parent/child relation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working on a complex angular application. Is there a way to `map` all your `scope`'s relations from `$rootScope` to the lowest level of your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `ng-inspector`. Its a great tool for checking scope heirarchy. You can find it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek?hl=en-US I use it on my Angular projects to dissect all the scopes. There's other features but I only really use that one. Once you install it it will be in your dev tools.

Comment: Great, but is there other ways that do not include dev tools?

Comment: Are you more interested in seeing the parent/child relationships between scopes or want to know what is inside a certain scope? If you don't want to use dev tools you can log a parent scope of a controller with $scope.$parent. But I'd really suggest using what TehBeardedOne posted, it seems a lot cleaner and more organized than the tool I posted and will save you from having to print out a bunch of different scopes in a console.